# How can I get a tbl of per game career stats for every (or almost every) NBA player in history?

Tags: r, csv, statistics, tbl

I've tried this using nbastatR:

```
library(nbastatR)
assign_nba_players()
players <- df_dict_nba_players$idPlayer
nba_careers <- players_careers(player_ids= players, modes="PerGame")
```

But it just ran for multiple days straight. Eventually, I checked Task Manager and saw that  "RStudio R Session" was taking up 0 computing power. So I terminated the program. [This](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wyattowalsh/basketball) appears to be a good alternative, but I'm not sure how to get the csv file I need and convert it into a tbl in RStudio. I'm only a few weeks old to R, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got some code using `rvest` to scrape Basketball-Reference here, that gets individual-level statistics for box scores by year: https://github.com/markhwhiteii/blog/blob/master/sloppy_play/sloppy_scraping.R

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way you know of to get per-game career statistics? (One row for every player, not one row for every player in every season they played.)